# "Confirm user presence for key" message not displayed when using Yubikey for SSH connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, yubikey

I have created SSH key on Yubikey 5 Nano using FIDO2:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-sk
```

The Yubikey has user and admin PIN set.

When using the key for establishing a SSH connection however, there is no message about requiring to touch the key like on the Github blog [Security keys are now supported for SSH Git operations](https://github.blog/2021-05-10-security-keys-supported-ssh-git-operations/):

```
Confirm user presence for key ...
```

In verbose mode the SSH client displays:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /.../.ssh/id_ed25519-sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... explicit authenticator agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /.../.ssh/id_ed25519-sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... explicit authenticator agent
```

at which point the Yubikey starts flashing. Once I touch it, the SSH login succeeds with that key and the subsequent messages will be:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com (via proxy).
```

When using the key for Git operations like `git clone` or `git pull`, it just silently waits for the key tap. The issue I have with this behavior is I don't know whether the SSH client is waiting for the network/server/proxy or for me to touch the key.

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with OpenSSH 8.2p1 (and Git 2.28.0). I am using the default ssh-agent and I can see the key listed in the 'Passwords and keys' application in Gnome under 'OpenSSH keys'.

Using `ssh-keygen` compiled from the OpenSSH 9.0p1 portable source, I can see that the public key has the flags set to 0x1 (user presence required):

```
$ ./ssh-keygen -vvv -y -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-sk
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com AAAAGnNrLX...mAAAABHNzaDo= foo@bar
debug1: sk_application: "ssh:", sk_flags 0x01
```

This flag should in theory trigger the message however it does not.
The OpenSSH 9.0p1 SSH client has the same behavior so I assume this lack of the message is caused by something in my setup.

Adding some debug debug code to `identity_sign()` in `sshconnect2.c`, I can see it calls `ssh_agent_sign()` and returns. Checking the source code of `process_sign_request2()` in `ssh-agent.c`, it contains the code to emit the message for "sk" keys.

When the SSH client is waiting for the key touch, the relevant process tree looks like this:

```
gnome-keyring-d(57868)-+-ssh-agent(58517)---ssh-sk-helper(79174)
                       |-{gnome-keyring-d}(57869)
                       |-{gnome-keyring-d}(57870)
                       |-{gnome-keyring-d}(57982)
                       `-{gnome-keyring-d}(79173)
```

Once the key touch happens, the `ssh-sk-helper` process goes away.

So it seems like if `ssh-agent` emitted the message, it did not get to the `ssh` process.

Comment: Git literally just runs ssh (with some arguments) so if it works from ssh, it seems like it should "just work" from Git too. You might try turning on `GIT_TRACE` to watch Git run ssh for debug purposes, and/or use `strace` to see what ssh itself does differently once invoked by Git.

Comment: It does not work from SSH actually.

Comment: Oh. Well, in that case, start there, not with Git.

Comment: Had the same issue. found the solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/784663/299187

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround than proper answer, however it provides a way to fix the behavior. There are multiple factors (sic!) to this:

Firstly, there is something in Ubuntu which is automatically adding the keys in `~/.ssh` directory to the `ssh-agent` started on login - once I create a key using `ssh-keygen`, the key appears automatically in the output of `ssh-add -l`. It is probably not ssh itself, because I do not have `AddKeysToAgent` set in my `~/.ssh/config` (or the global config) and the default value of this directive is `no`.

To overcome this behavior, I generated the key files in different location (`~/altssh`).

Next, ssh prefers the keys stored in ssh-agent so this needs to be changed as well, using the `IdentitiesOnly` directive set to `yes`.

The ssh configuration snippet that makes the 'Confirm user presence' message to be emitted:

```
Host *github.com                                                                
  User git                                                                      
                                                                                
  # ssh will prefer the keys stored in ssh-agent to the one from                
  # the identity file so this behavior needs to be changed.                     
  IdentitiesOnly yes                                                            
  # for a good measure                                                          
  IdentityAgent none                                                            
                                                                                
  # The keys from ~/.ssh will be added to the ssh-agent automatically           
  # which I want to avoid because then the 'Confirm user presence'              
  # message will not be displayed.                                              
  IdentityFile ~/altssh/id_ed25519-sk
```

With this in place, it works:

```
$ ssh-add -l | grep 25519 | wc -l
0
$ ssh -T github.com
Confirm user presence for key ED25519-SK SHA256:...
Hi ...! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Still, I think this is a limitation of how the ssh-agent communication works in OpenSSH. Also, perhaps Ubuntu should not be adding the `sk` keys to the ssh-agent as a second level workaround.

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem on Debian 12, `IdentitiesOnly` + `IdentityAgent` did the job, you made my days so much better man thank you